# Give the description of all commutative rings with unity of $8$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The task is to give the description of all (with the precision of isomorphism) commutative rings with unity of $8$ elements.

As for addition definition, I understood that the are two options for the sum of the units: $1+1=0$ and $8 = 0$, for if $n = 0$ we will get a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_n$, and its amount of elements in should be the power of $n$, which is possible only for $2$ and $8$: $2^3$ and $8^1$. In both cases addition is completely defined.

In the case of $8 = 0$ the ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(8)$.

In the second case we can consider the ring as vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of dimension $3$, with elements $\{1, 0, a, a+1,b,b+1,a+b,a+b+1\}$. Now the structure of the ring depends on the definition of multiplication in it. The only fact that I understood about it is that if we define $a^2=a$ and $b^2=b$ then for any element $r$ of the ring $r^2=r$, hence it is boolean ring, which in turn is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$.

Also I know that if we define $a^2=a+1$, then $\{1, 0, a, a+1\}$ is a field of $4$ elements, but how is it connected with the structure of the complete ring?

What are the other options for multiplication and what do they mean in terms of the ring structure?

Comment: I would think $\Bbb F_4×\Bbb F_2$ would be the third option.

Comment: It's not $\mathbb{F}_4$. All the $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ have characteristic $2$

Comment: you also have, e.g., $(\mathbb{Z}/4)[X]$ where $X^2=0$.

Comment: Please search before asking. I found the duplicate by putting your question in the search bar.